# Applicant option not showing in thunderbird addon in openerp

Tags: odoo, thunderbird-addon

I am using openerp 6.1.1 and trying to create an applicant from thunderbird addon.

I have created a custom module to add some extra fields to the hr_applicant model.

The thunderbird OpenERP addon does not show the option to create an Applicant.

When I remove the custom module, I am able to see the option in the thunderibird add on.

I am not clear what am I doing wrong in the custom module:

```
class hr_applicant_custom (osv.osv):
  _name = 'hr.applicant'
  _inherit = 'hr.applicant'
  _columns = {
    'year_passing': fields.integer('Passing Year', help='Year of passing'),
    'experience': fields.float('Experience', digits=(3,1)),    
  }
hr_applicant_custom()
```

Please advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Thunderbird, module you can see the model which are inheriting the model `mail.thread`  for this behavior  reposnsible method is [`message_capable_models`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/head:/mail/mail_thread.py#L61), Which will filter model which are inheriting the model `mail.thread`

In your case if you see closely in code of the module `hr_recruitment` you will find `hr.applicant` model is [inheriting](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/6.1/view/head:/hr_recruitment/hr_recruitment.py#L95) the `mail.thread`, so you will see it under TB Push Mai list, now in your module what you are doing is modifying the `_inherit` attribute of the model `hr.applicant`  so due to python MRO this will be change to new class and now this model is not eligible for creating new record.

***Solution :*** you should try multiple model in `_inherit` like `inherit = ['mail.thread', 'hr.applicant']`

Hope this will help.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.  
By the way, I tried `class hr_applicant_custom(hr_applicant)` but that didn't work.  
Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: @helloworld `class hr_applicant_custom(hr_applicant)` this didnot work because again as i said Python MRO play big role, in class inheritance if you will give `_inherit` different value then the latest code will play role and what we did in both case here is preserved the previous value and used new value, this possible casue of Flexibility of the OpenERP Framework, else Here Python MRO is Headache. , hope you getting the point